# How to use the switch statement on UIImagePickerControllerMediaType?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, uiimagepickercontroller

How do I use the switch statement on `UIImagePickerControllerMediaType`?

The following example throws the strange compiler error:

> Expression pattern of type 'CFString' cannot match values of type
>   'CFString'.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    switch info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! CFString {

    case kUTTypeImage:
        break

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can suggest two ways to solve this inconvenience.

## Cast to String

Simple, but requires extra typing.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    switch info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! String {
        case String(kUTTypeImage):
            break
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

## Implement pattern matching operator for CFString type

More tricky, but less typing if you need switching on `CFString` often.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    switch info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! CFString {
        case kUTTypeImage:
            break
        default:
            break
    }
}

func ~=(pattern: CFString, value: CFString) -> Bool {
    return pattern == value
}
```

See section "Expression Pattern" in [Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html) chapter in the language reference (Swift 2.2).

Comment: Pattern matching operator 

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is casting to `NSString`:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    switch info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString {
        case kUTTypeImage:
            break
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution.

Comment: @werediver Yes even shorter, thanks for pointing out the valuable background info on expression patterns in your answer though.